# SGH-S730M SAMSUNG DESCOVER

Tags: locked-out

i have my sgh-s730m Android phone my problem is my screen is being locked it appears EMERGENCY CALL can you help me on how to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I don't know your device by the "technical name". But usually this indicates that there's either no SIM inserted/detected, or you didn't unlock the SIM (it's usually protected by a PIN), or the SIM is locked due to entering incorrect PINs. Can you provide some details on these facts? Does any of them match your current state?

Answer (score 0):

You should call an operator to fix this kind of problem

Comment: Why? And what operator? Isn't there anything the OP can try before that? What is "this kind of problem", and what stands behind it? See my comment on the question itself: there are some things which should be veryfied before contacting service. The solution might be as trivial as putting a SIM card into the device.

Comment: I think the problem is already on the phone.I cant give what is the solution for this problem because I don't know what happened before this situation came up.In that case I suggest that you should take a test.Insert a new sim card or use another sim card.If you did this one and the same problem occurred again.I guess the problem is on your phone.OR when you did this and this problem didn't happened then the problem is on the sim card itself.

Comment: That should have been part of your answer :) Especially the example procedure of trying with different SIM cards. Would you mind to [edit] your answer, and include that part, so it's easier to make out? Thanks!